# Request API on another VM

Tags: vagrant, ansible, virtualbox, vmware

I have actually 2 VM with ansible, one deploy our Django project, and one deploy all our WordPress websites.

We made a WordPress plugin which request the REST API of the Django project. The problem is: I want to dev in local on my Django project and for that I must enter the URL of the Django project in the WordPress plugin we made.
But the problem is, the URL is accessible from the host machine but not on the other VM.

VagrantFile port config of the Django VM :

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8443,   host: 8443
```

VagrantFile port config of the Wordpress VM :

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5580,   host: 5580
```

Sorry for my bad english

Thanks in advance;

Comment: you better build a private network with static IP so you would be able to enter the static IP of your Django server in the other box and ping/access directly using the IP

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in each VM's Vagrantfile :

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "IPADDRESS"
```

Substitute `IPADDRESS` with a fitting IP and this way you can access whichever VM you would like through the set IP. You would need both VM's running at the same time in order for communication to be successful though.